# Why didn't I get the desirable output?

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append_first(self, data):
        node = Node(data, self.head)
        self.head = node

    def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Linked List Is Empty")
            return
        itr = self.head
        llst = ""

        while itr:
            llst += str(itr.data) + "--->"
            itr = itr.next

        print(llst)

    def append_last(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)

        itr = self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next


        itr.next = Node(data, None)

    def append_multiple(self, multiple_data):
        self.head = None
        for data in multiple_data:
            self.append_last(data)


a = LinkedList()
a.append_multiple(["a", "b", "c"])
a.print()


//Output: a--->a--->b--->c--->
```

I was currently learning Linked List and just learned to add multiple elements in the list.

As the given input is "a", "b", "c" . However the code returns

```
a--->a--->b--->c--->
```

Why is that? Why is the first element being duplicated?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `dsa`?  What does this have to do with Digital Signature Algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return from your `append_last()` method. When the linked list is empty `(self.head = None)`, is working fine you add a new node and designate it to be the head. However, to avoid adding another node at the end, you must `return` from the method.

Updated code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append_first(self, data):
        node = Node(data, self.head)
        self.head = node

    def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Linked List Is Empty")
            return
        itr = self.head
        llst = ""

        while itr:
            llst += str(itr.data) + "--->"
            itr = itr.next

        print(llst)

    def append_last(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return

        itr = self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next


        itr.next = Node(data, None)

    def append_multiple(self, multiple_data):
        self.head = None
        for data in multiple_data:
            self.append_last(data)


a = LinkedList()
a.append_multiple(["a", "b", "c"])
a.print()
```

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 1):

In `append_last` addition of the first element passes the condition `if self.head is None:`, so one copy is created.

Then the execution for the first element doesn't stop and continues adding another copy.

You should add `return` like this:

```
    def append_last(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return

        itr = self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next


        itr.next = Node(data, None)
```

Comment: If it did, @AKiNir, then you should consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the issues with Node linking, you could do away with the print() function by implementing __str__ like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, node=None):
        self._value = value
        self._next = node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None

    def append_first(self, value):
        self._head = Node(value, self._head)

    def append_last(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = node
        else:
            temp = self._head
            while temp._next is not None:
                temp = temp._next
            temp._next = node

    def append_multiple(self, lst):
        for value in lst:
            self.append_last(value)

    def __str__(self):
        if self._head:
            values = []
            temp = self._head
            while temp:
                values.append(temp._value)
                temp = temp._next
            return '--->'.join(map(str, values))
        return 'Linked list is empty'


linkedList = LinkedList()

linkedList.append_multiple(["a", "b", "c"])

print(linkedList)
```

**Output:**

```
a--->b--->c
```